# how to compare strings with data from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

i am working on project that need to compare strings (user id and password) that i get from bluetooth, store it in sqlite then compare it with strings that i get from editTexts (user id and password). i can read input from bluetooth and store it in sqlite but i don't know how to compare it with data that i get from editTexts. can you help me?

here is mydBHelper Activity:

```
public class myDbAdapter {

myDbHelper myhelper;
public myDbAdapter(Context context)
{
    myhelper = new myDbHelper(context);
}


public long insertData(String userid, String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase dbb = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(myDbHelper.UID, userid);
    contentValues.put(myDbHelper.MyPASSWORD, pass);
    long id = dbb.insert(myDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null , contentValues);
    return id;
}



static class myDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";    // Database Name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "myTable";   // Table Name
    private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;    // Database Version
    private static final String UID="_id";     // Column I (Primary Key)
    private static final String MyPASSWORD= "Password";    // Column III
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+
            " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"+ MyPASSWORD+" VARCHAR(225));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;

    public myDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_Version);
        this.context=context;
    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Message.message(context,""+e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Message.message(context,"OnUpgrade");
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Message.message(context,""+e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

the string that i got was inserted into FromServer Activity:

```
public class FromServer extends AppCompatActivity {
myDbAdapter helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_from_server);
    //Userid_txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserID);
    //Pass_txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);
    helper = new myDbAdapter(this);

}

//insert string from bluetooth
public void insertData() {
    //----------------passed string from bluetooth
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("moved");
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);

        String t1 = obj.getString("user_id");
        String t2 = obj.getString("password");
        if (t1.isEmpty() || t2.isEmpty()) {
            Message.message(getApplicationContext(), "User ID and Password empty");
        }

        long id = helper.insertData(t1, t2);
        if (id >= 0) {

            Message.message(getApplicationContext(), "Insertion success");

        } else {
            Message.message(getApplicationContext(), "Insertion to database failed");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Then, in Main Activity i create userid.getText and password.getText that will be compare with my data from sqlite. i'm new in sqlite, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The following method in the myDbAdapter class would return true if there is matching data or false otherwise.

```
public boolean compareData(String userid, String pass)
{
    boolean rv = false;
    SQLiteDatabase dbb = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = myDbHelper.UID + "=? AND " + myDbHelper.MyPASSWORD + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{userid,pass};
    Cursor csr = dbb.query(myDbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
        rv = true;
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- This queries the table using SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE _id='????' AND Password='????';
- The result of the query is returned as a Cursor.
- The Cursor's count (number of returned rows) is checked, if it's greater than 0 (should only ever be 0 or 1 due to _id), the the data matches otherwise there are no rows found (0 count).
- The Cursor is closed and either false or true returned (the latter if both columns matched).

You could be invoke this using something like :-

```
if(helper.compareData(Userid_txt.getText().toString(),Pass_txt.getText().toString()) {
    .... handle data compares
} else {
    .... handle data does not compare
}
```

You would probably want to make **`Userid_txt`** and **`Pass_Txt`** class variables and to also have a means of invoking the above after data has been entered (perhaps a button). So assuming a button then you could have something like :-

```
public class FromServer extends AppCompatActivity {
    myDbAdapter helper;
    EditText Userid_txt, Pass_txt;
    Button doCompare; 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_from_server);
        Userid_txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserID);
        Pass_txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);
        doCompare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
        helper = new myDbAdapter(this);

        doCompare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

helper.compareData(Userid_txt.getText().toString(),Pass_txt.getText().toString()) {
                    //.... handle data compared
                } else {
                    //.... handle data doesn't compare
                }
            }
        });    
    }
    ......
```

- Note the above is in-principle code and has not been tested so it may contain some errors.